# author global display format

Tags: custom-field, author

Does someone know how to change format of the author link display? ie.
Under Post Title i have meta fields where i display

> May 8th, 2017 by Author_Nickname on Category &Views ≈ 0

Author_Nickname is as active link to all posts by this author.
and this is ok. 
I am using the_author() function for this purpose.
However when i click the link then Author_Nickname is being change to Author-email. i.e.

> http://myweb.com/author/Author_Emailgmail-com/

Author_Email@gmail.com is author email. So email is being used. 
How to change the link to the following

> http://myweb.com/author/Author_Nickname/

I dont want to display publicly author email only nickname.
Thank you for your help

Comment: This depends on the theme you are using, not on WP itself.

Comment: It is probably because the `username` of the user is an email address. Wordpress uses for author permalinks the `username` field. You probably cannot change the `username` into a "normal" username and not an email?

Comment: yes, this is (was) the problem. done

Answer (score 0):

Try this as

`<?php echo get_the_author_link(); ?>`

and see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_link

Comment: No, this works wery well, i have this code 
<?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>  by <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')) ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a> on <span class="blog-meta-cat"><?php the_category(' | '); ?></span> The problem is that Wordpress display in web address email instead of Nickname as described above. Thanks